# How can I create a sheets formula to update adjusted score and rank when rows are removed from the data set?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, iteration, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a data set that lists players, a rank, a score, and an adjusted score. here is sample data:

[image]

Pretty straight forward to get adjusted score:

```
=C3/(COUNTIF($B$3:$B$6,"<>"))
```

or the array version:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(C3:C/(COUNTIF($B$3:B,"<>")))
```

That formula works to update the adjusted score when someone is removed from the data set... however, I also need to update the rank so that the removal is accounted for. Here's an example of what the data would look like after this happens:

[image]

The best I can do is something like this copied down -

```
'=if(A3="","",(MIN(B$2:B)+COUNTA(A$2:A3)-1))
```

but that requires iterative calculations to be turned on and I would prefer not to have to do that. I would like a formula (i assume this would need to be an array formula but a i could see a query possibly working as well). I just need to make sure i can remove data from D when there's nothing in col A-C.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q-Kb1cFe7Y6MY03WKWvGQfUdV_Cfc00nsx5dtzy54TI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,ROW(A1:A)))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, {FILTER(A3:A, A3:A<>""), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A3:A"&COUNTA(A3:A)+(ROW(A3)-1)))-(ROW(A3)-1)}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]